# Knockoutjs Custom Binding style child

Tags: knockout.js, ko-custom-binding

I have a custom binding.

```
<div data-bind="autocomplete : { inputStyle : { marginRight : marginR }}"></div>
```

in my init function I do this. I add a inputbox that I need to be styled.

```
$element.append("<input type='text' data-bind='style='" + value.inputStyle + "' />");
```

I know this wont work, but please can somebody help me do it right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the custom binding doing what you requested:

```
function toStyleStr (obj) {
    var result = "";
    $.each(obj, function (k,v) {
        result += k.toString() + ": " + ko.utils.unwrapObservable(v).toString() + ";"; 
    });    
    return result;               
}

ko.bindingHandlers.autocomplete = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor()),
            $element = $(element);
        $element.append("<input type='text' style='" + toStyleStr(value.inputStyle) + "' />");     
    }            
};

var model = {
    marginR: ko.observable("10px")
};
ko.applyBindings(model);
```

Here is a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/RYnbR/2/

Answer (score 0):

Well I don't really understand what you want to do. But some comments:

```
$element.append("<input type='text' data-bind='style='" + value.inputStyle + "' />
```

doesn't work. Style binding receives an object with the style and the value:
something like

```
$element.append("<input type='text' data-bind='style:{color:#ff0000}' />");
```

so you could do

```
$element.append("<input type='text' data-bind='style:{color:"+value.inputStyle.marginRight +"}'/>");
```

this assuming marginR has a color as string.

But why data-bind it then ? You could do:

```
$element.append("<input type='text' style='color:"+value.inputStyle.marginRight +"'/>")
```

Comment: Yes as I said I understand that my code dosen't work. But the thing I want is to transfer the hole style binding down to my input. So I dont have to sepcify any color or so.